# class-based dictionary in python using pickle

Tags: python, class, dictionary, module, pickle

I want to define a class that implements some capabilities of a dictionary. I also want to store the objects after the program finished it's work with that object and load it when the program wants to reinitialize it. for this purpose I chose *pickle*. here's my **FileDict.py** code:

```
import pickle
class FileDict():

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.data_name = name

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 'alaki':
            return None
        elif key == 'data_name':
            return None
        else:
            return self.__dict__[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key == 'alaki':
            return None
        elif key == 'data_name':
            return None
        else:
            self.__dict__[key] = value

    def items(self):
        return self.__dict__.items()

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.__dict__)

    def __del__(self):
        f = open(str(self.data_name) + '.pkl', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(self, f)
        f.close()
```

in another python file, I write some codes as shown below and run it:

```
from FileDict import FileDict

data = FileDict('person1')

# when codes below are not commented 
data['name'] = 'mohsen'
data['family'] = 'mahmoodzadeh'
data['alaki'] = 'foo'
print(data['alaki'])
print(data)
#

# when codes below are commented 
'''data['name'] = 'mohsen'
data['family'] = 'mahmoodzadeh'
data['alaki'] = 'foo'
print(data['alaki'])
print(data)'''
#
```

when some codes I marked them whit #...# are not commented, I expect a result like this:

```
None
{'name': 'mohsen', 'family': 'mahmoodzadeh'}
```

but I got below:

```
None
{'data_name': 'person1', 'name': 'mohsen', 'family': 'mahmoodzadeh'}
```

and for when some codes I marked them whit #...# are commented, I expect a result like this:

```
None
{'name': 'mohsen', 'family': 'mahmoodzadeh'}
```

but I don't know how to do it.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: don't use `self.__dict__`, just use an attribute, `self.data = {}` and use that

Comment: You should probably have your `FileDict` inherit from `collections.abc.MutableMapping` and get most dictionary methods for free: [MutableMapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping) - I also recommend this video from @RaymondH that specifically talks about subclassing a python dict to make a permanent one using files: https://youtu.be/S_ipdVNSFlo?t=1795